# serialize / unserialize php object

Tags: php, html, forms, serialization

I am having trouble understanding the concept of serialize/unserialize in PHP.

Assume I have a very simple PHP object (class someObject) and after setting the attributes of that object I want to serialize it:

So I call: `serialize($someObject)`;

I want to transfer this serialized object into another php skript via a html form so I set it as a hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someObject" value="<? print $someObject; ?>"
```

In the next php script I want to use unserialize to get my object back and transfer it e.g. to a databae.

```
$unserialize = unserialize($_POST['someObject'])
```

But this always returns BOOL(false) - so what am I missing here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: well .. make a `var_dump( $_POST['someObject'] );` and see .. also, you should use sessions for this, not hidden input fields.

Comment: What does $_POST['someObject'] contain in the second script?

Comment: I'm not aware of any guarantees that the serialized string won't contain `"`, and if it does, the generated HTML will be broken. If unserialize() can't deserialize the object, it will return `false`

Comment: when I var_dump that I get BOOL(false)

Answer (score 5):

A serialized string looks like this:

```
O:1:"a":1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"100";}
```

You have to`urlencode`/`urldecode` the serialized string to prevent any characters in the serialized representation from breaking your markup. Have a look at your page source. The first quote likely ended your HTML value attribute. So you got something like:

```
<input ... value="O:1:"a":1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"100";}">
```

So your `$_POST` will never contain the full serialized string, but only `O:1:`

If this is not the issue, make sure you got a serialized string from the object in the first place. Also please be aware that there some objects cannot be serialized or have modified behavior when (un)serialized. Please refer to the [Notes in PHP Manual for `serialize` for details.](http://php.net/serialize)

If you dont need to send objects across different servers running PHP, consider persisting them in a [Session](http://php.net/sessions) instead. It's easier, less error prone and more secure because the object cannot be tampered with while in transit.

Comment: @MrBr well, yes. thats the more sensible solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the class defined in your second script before you unserialize() the object

Comment: hm I am not sure if I understand correct so I use something like `$object = new someObject();` and later on `$unserialized = unserialize($_POST['someObject']); $object = $unserialized` ? This also returns FALSE in my case

Comment: Well you seem to be confusing defining a class and instantiating an object.... $object = new someObject() is instantiating an object... you must already have defined the someObject class before you can do this. The act of unserializing a serialized object will then create the object instance, so your $unserialized = unserialize($_POST['someObject']); wil do this, creating an object in the variable $unserialized.... $object = $unserialized; will create a clone of the $unserialized object. Please try to identify exactly where your error is occurring